# Elasticsearch Result more like google

Tags: ajax, laravel, elasticsearch

Is there posibilities to load only that terms what i am looking for ? Example if i search [ expert ] word it will look in suggested_tags and output result according to that ?

Right now if i type child it takes all terms and it makes file size big and it takes time to show autocomplete.

Here is [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EsqH.png)

When we search in google it shows result like this :

[Google Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh9pG.png)

So it is possible in elasticsearch ? because i don't want to load all suggested_tags while searching only load 4 or 5 related to search and doesn't metter for position.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `fuzziness` ?

Comment: Also if you paste come code, like your mapping, sample indexed `JSON` etc then it will be helpful.

Comment: yes i try fuzziness if you goto elastic.co you can see by inspect element elasticsearch json only shows name and one other filed in json but if you goto my website http://crowdfunds.in and goto inspect element and search something in searchbox you can see result in network tab or resources tab elasticsearch output everything that i not wanted..

Comment: I used "_source" : ["name"] it works fine but i don't wanted to unnessery fields like _score, _shrade etc.

Comment: I think this is an open issue. Check http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/URI-Request-that-returns-just-the-source-without-metadata-td4021192.html

Comment: yes i saw and still discussing about it :)